# Symfony After Filters - modify json response

Tags: php, json, symfony

Does anyone knows how to add new data field to existing JsonResponse (`Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse`) in after filter (`onKernelResponse`) without deleting old data?

For example, I have custom controller

```
<?php
class MessageController extends Controller
{

    public function getAllMessagesAction(Request $request)
    {
        (...)

        return new JsonResponse(array(
            'count' => count($messages),
            'total_count' => $allMessagesCount,
            'messages' => $messages,
        ));
    }
}
```

and some listener

```
<?php
class NotesListener
{
    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        (...)

        $response = $event->getResponse();
        if ($response instanceof JsonResponse) {
            $response->setData(array('foo' => 'bar'));
        }
    }
}
```

### Problem

The problem is that `$response->setData` in listener will override data passed in controller. Moreover, `JsonResponse` doesn't have method like `addData()`. Unfortunately there is not method `getData()`, so I can not get old data, modifying it, and set new data.

Does anyone know good solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're really close, but the methods you are looking for are called `setContent()` and `getContent()`. Also [see the API docs](http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.html) of JsonResponse.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `getContent()` and decode the the data, then modify it and set the data again.

Alternatively, you could change your controller to just return the data and create the `JsonResponse` in an event listener.

Comment: yes, `json_decode($response->getContent(), true);` seems to be best solution. But on the other hand what if there will be multiple listeners and response content will contain more then 1k of elements? This could slow down whole application. I am now thinking, maybe better way is to extend `JsonResponse` with own class and add `getData` method?